# Selecting rows with multiple values for a column

Tags: mysql, sql, rows

On MySQL, Given the following table (image_tags):

```
image_id | tag_id
-----------------
1        | 100
1        | 20
2        | 100
3        | 20
```

I would like to select the rows where tag_id=100 AND tag_id=20, my desired result in this case would be:

```
image_id
--------
1
```

I tried but I couldn't find a proper way to do it in pure SQL. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT image_id FROM MyTable
WHERE tag_id IN (100,20)
GROUP BY image_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

If you want to select every rows then try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE image_id IN
(
    SELECT image_id FROM MyTable
    WHERE tag_id IN (100,20)
    GROUP BY image_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
)
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c972b/9)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the (`image_id`, `tag_id`) pair is unique:

```
SELECT image_id
FROM image_tags
WHERE tag_id IN ('20', '100')
GROUP BY image_id
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple JOIN query

```
SELECT a.image
FROM image_tags a
INNER JOIN image_tags b ON a.image_id = b.image_id AND b.tag_id = 20
WHERE a.tag_id = 100
```

or using counts, but coping if there are duplicates tags for an image

```
SELECT DISTINCT image_id
FROM image_tags
WHERE tag_id in ('20', '100')
GROUP BY image_id
HAVING count(DISTINCT tag_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

what you did is right you can also try this

> select * from image_tags where tag_id in ('100','20',....)

Comment: I cannot use IN, it will give back the rows where tag_id=100 OR tag_id=20,...
I need image_id WHERE tag_id = 100 AND tag_id = 20, on my example this would be image_id=1, hope it makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Image_ID FROM 
(SELECT Image_ID FROM tab
WHERE Tag_ID = 100) tag100
JOIN
(SELECT Image_Id FROM tab
WHERE TagID = 20) tag20
```

I think this is what you're looking for you - you want those records which have both a TagID that is equal to 20 and a TagID equal to 100, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
select image_id 
from image_tags 
where image_id IN (
            select image_id 
            from image_tags 
            where tag_id = 100) 
AND tag_id = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
select image_id from test
where image_id IN (select image_id from test
where tag_id = '100') AND tag_id = '20'
```

check [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e84b/13)

Comment: Thanks! Sub-queries works good, but would it be efficient with more than two values? lets say tag_id=100 AND tag_id=20 AND tag_id=30?

Comment: You can use `select DISTINCT  image_id from test
where image_id IN (select image_id from test where tag_id = '100') 
AND image_id IN (select image_id from test where tag_id = '20') 
AND image_id IN (select image_id from test where tag_id = '30')`

Comment: Is it more efficient than `SELECT image_id FROM MyTable
WHERE tag_id IN (100,20,30)
GROUP BY image_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3` ?